# How could you design a dishwasher to always be able to tell whether the dishes are clean or dirty?

Tags: ux-field, physical

One problem my roommates and I have is figuring out whether the dishes are dirty or clean. How could you design a dishwasher to always tell whether the dishes inside are clean or dirty? How can we work around the current dishwasher design to figure out whether the dishes are clean or dirty?

Comment: You can usually tell by looking at the dishes. Barring that, newer dishwashers usually have some sort of status display indicating the cycle is finished.

Comment: This is more of a discussion topic than an answerable question and therefore isn't a good fit for a Q&A site. Are you able to tighten up the question so that it can solicit a definate answer?

Comment: FWIW, I disagree with closing this, There is a clear question here, and it does relate to physical person-machine interfaces. It could do with some enhancement, but I think there is a good question in here

Comment: What about lamp, that will signal this condition: washing cycle has finished and dish is still there (door weren't opened, or dish rack not moved)? Wanted to post as answer, I do not agree with closing this question, too.

Comment: this is one of those google interview questions, isnt it? How could you weigh an elephant without scales etc etc? how do you know if the firdge door light has gone out once you've closed the door?

Comment: A similar but more pressing question relates to washing machines:  there is often no reminder that there is a load of wet washing sitting, festering in them.   I resort to leaving the soap powder sitting on the worktop as a reminder that the machine needs emptying.

Comment: I also think this is a legitimate design question.

Comment: Was this a homework assignment?

Comment: The lack of integration of electronics in kitchens is quite depressing: what's needed are appliances which can talk to smart phones.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a UX issue; this is not asking 'should' the washer tell if the dishes are clean or dirty, but 'how'. This is engineering or design; implementation. Not experience.

Comment: It does seem like dishwasher designers assume each appliance will only have one operator, who can remember what state it's in. A dishwasher has 4 states: empty, partially/fully loaded, running, clean + needs unloading. If one roommate opens the door after a cycle, but doesn't immediately unload the dishwasher, the clean light @DA01 cited will be cleared, and the information it provides is lost. Thus an un-illuminated clean light can only rule out the 'running' state. I believe OP is asking for a design that will always clearly distinguish 'clean' from the first two states (empty or loaded).

Answer (score 5):

Weigh the dishes. A dishwasher that had a built-in scale could tell when something had been added rather than taking out. If the weight increases while the door is open, then the contents are dirty. If the weight has only decreased so far, then everything is still clean. This would fail on edge cases like taking out a clean dish and putting in a dirty one at the same time, but most people don't [pretend to be Indiana Jones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gU35Tgtlmg) while managing their dishes.

Comment: It is important to note that Indiana Jones didn't make the switch right (it is for the audience to try and recall whether his bag of sand was too heavy or too light). But he was able to run fast though.